# Paramertized SQL, Oracle 11g, and C# Failing to create index

Tags: c#, indexing, oracle11g

I am trying to use a parametrized query to create an index on our Oracle server. I can create the index fine if I use string concatenation, so I believe its not an account or permissions issue. I get the error:

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I can not find any error in the code, but I am sure I am missing something. I am using Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 4.112.3.0. The version the server reports is "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production"

I have tried removing all the params, except one and get the same error. Any combination of 1 or more params causes the error. The error happens every time without fail. I have used watches to verify that the params are correctly getting set, and I have tried clearing the params before setting. No matter what I do so far, I still get the error. Here is the code:

```
using (OracleCommand mycom = new OracleCommand())
        {
            using (OracleConnection Connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                mycom.BindByName = true;
                mycom.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX :indexname on :tablename (:colname)";
                mycom.Parameters.Add("indexname", indexName);
                mycom.Parameters.Add("tablename", tableName);
                mycom.Parameters.Add("colname", colName);

                mycom.Connection = Connection;
                mycom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                mycom.Connection.Open();
                mycom.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use bind variables in a DDL statement (like `CREATE INDEX`).  Bind variables are only used in DML statements.  You would need to build up the DDL statement in your C# code.

Is this a part of the installation process for your application?  Otherwise, it would be exceedingly unusual to want to create an index from an application.  Your application shouldn't be creating any database objects outside of the initial installation process.

Comment: It does because before the index is created there is no rows in the in tables, then the feed inserts millions of rows. The design decision was to make the indexes after those inserts instead of before.